# Submit a form to another directory file

Tags: html, forms, jsp, directory

The directory structure is as shown below

```
           WEB-INF
            |
            |-xfolder
            |-sample.jsp
            |-images/man/upload.html
            |
```

Now how to submit the upload.html form to sample.jsp page

I tried like this in upload.html file

```
  <form method="post" action="../sample.jsp" >
       ......
       .......

  </form>
```

But it not worked.
Help me..

Comment: Is it called `upload.html` because you are uploading a file? If so, you need to add  `enctype= multipart/form-data` to your form declaration.

Comment: still it's not submitting

Comment: Your path is also wrong: As per your structure posted, it should be `action=../../sample.jsp` You need to go up 2 levels; one for man and one for images, to get to the root.

Comment: And you can't access files and JSPs stored inside WEB-INF from the outside. The files need to be out of the WEB-INF directory.

Comment: You can't just use request.getParameter() with `multipart/form-data`. you need Apache Commons File Upload library.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are uploading files, you need to include `enctype= multipart/form-data` in your form declaration

Second -and most likely your problem- your form's action is wrong. It should be: `action="../../sample.jsp"` since you need to go up 2 levels: one for `man` and one more for `images` to get to the root where `sample.jsp` is located.